# windows server 2016 asp.net app hosting

Tags: visual-studio, iis, windows-server-2008, web-hosting, windows-server-2016

ive been searching for about 2 week on how to host asp.net web app on windows server 2016 on my home machine(server) with no luck. its so confusing and ive never used windows server before but i am very interested in that topic. if u can point me to the right direction that would be awesome.

so i need to:

1. setup windows server for hosting asp.net mvc web app with database
2. setup sqlserver db with all permissions and stuff that goes with it
3. be able to access web app on local server
4. be able to deploy web app from visual studio on dev pc to server (both on local network)
5. access and use web app in local network
6. and if possible make it public so any one on the web can access it (this is just for the fun of it, and to learn how hosting works)

Comment: [Learn how to ask a question please](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Each of the tasks you stated have been discussed countlessly over the internet, and there is no need to duplicate.

Comment: thanks for that. can u post links to that threads. i am kinda lost and i dont know what to search

Comment: You can try to find shared hosting provider, it will be easier, you just need to upload your files to the server, no need server administration. You can take a look at hostforlife.eu. They support .net core services.